# Planned Risk:Reward in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

I would like to know if there's a way to have a planned risk reward on a study in pinescript.
With planned risk reward I mean that I choose to riks, for example, 2% of my capital. If stoploss is triggered, no matter if it's a 200pips or a 5 pips stoploss, I loose 2% of my capital.

I tried to search allover internet and even asked on pinescripters telegram group but sadly found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make the calculations yourself in a study. The answer to this question shows how:
[Pinescript set a position size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62980054/11806240)